# How do i bind the variable value to the view page at runtime in mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, model

This is some serious issue which i'm facing for a quite long time 3 hours, i suppose but no fix found and i'm stuck.
                             So here i have developed a Patient registration Page in asp.net mvc 4 razor which will be posting the form data to the database if validation comes out to true, but before that i need to call a random variable object which will be storing a random value within prespecified range and insert that variable into the view which is strongly typed(connected to the patients model class) ,

created with create template such that the fields or properties of the patients class are acessed in the view to store patients data into the view.
   Now,Here i need a random value **(patient's ID)** to be preselected into the *patient ID textbox* each time the PatientRegistration page is called so that it works like a unique token generator for every new patient registered.

I have tried several other codes to bind the random value into the form element for patient id but none of them worked for me.Below i'm writing code for my model class,controller and the regisrtation view(cshtml).Please Help me in this!

Patients model class:-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;


namespace OnlineDoctorApppointment.Models
{

    public class Patients
    {

         //public string PatientId { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Patient Name")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Patient Name is required")]
        [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 3)]
        [RegularExpression("^([A-Z][a-z]+([ ]?[a-z]?['-]?[A-Z][a-z]+)*)$", ErrorMessage = "Only alphabets are required")]
        public string PatientName { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Patient Age")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Age is required")]
        [Range(0, 100, ErrorMessage = "Age must be between 0 and 100")]
        public int Age { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your email address")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        [Display(Name = "Email address")]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        [RegularExpression(@"[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}", ErrorMessage = "Please enter correct email")]
        public string PatientEmail { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Patient Mobile number")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Your Mobile Number")]
        [RegularExpression(@"(\+)?(91)?( )?[789]\d{9}", ErrorMessage = "Please enter correct format")]
        public int PatientMobileNo { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Password")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter password")]
        [RegularExpression(@"(?=(.*[a-z])+)(?=(.*[0-9])+)[0-9a-zA-Z!#$%&'()*+,\-.\/:;<=>?@\[\\\]^_`{|}~]{8,15}", ErrorMessage = "Your Password must contain minimum 8 characters consisting of atleast one numeral and alphabets")]
        public string PatientPassword { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Patient ID")]
        public string PatientID
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

Patient Registration .cshtml:-

```
@model OnlineDoctorApppointment.Models.Patients

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>PatientRegistration</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Patients</legend>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PatientName)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PatientName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PatientName)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Age)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Age)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Age)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PatientEmail)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PatientEmail)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PatientEmail)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PatientMobileNo)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PatientMobileNo)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PatientMobileNo)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PatientPassword)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PatientPassword)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PatientPassword)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PatientID)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">

               @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PatientID, new { @Value = ViewBag.PatientID })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PatientID)

            </div>

            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Create" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    }

    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using OnlineDoctorApppointment.Models;

namespace OnlineDoctorApppointment.Controllers
{
    public class LoginController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Login/

        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult PatientLogin()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult DoctorLogin()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult PatientRegistration()
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            int patientid = random.Next(1000, 100000);

            ViewBag.PatientID = patientid;
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you needing that in the view? That should only be created and saved in the POST method. And why are you using a random value instread of using an auto-incremented key - you ID will not even be unique!. (and if for some reason you ever did need to do this, you initialise a new instance of the model in the GET method, assign the value to the `PatientID` property and return the model to the view`. Do not use `ViewBag` and never set the `value` attribute when using the `HtmlHelper` methods

Comment: @StephenMuecke sir first,I need that in the view because i want to show the user who register their login ID and i do consider that using random will not be unique everytime but please suggest me the code in answer how to do that which you are telling me!

Comment: You tell then the ID after they have posted the form - there is no point telling them something which does not even exist yet (it has not been saved anywhere)